# Huge input lookup error on simplexml_load_string function

Tags: php, simplexml

I have an API response where sizes vary. It doesn't show error on large xml data(appx. 20MB), when I try to convert the xml object into std object using.
This is my code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($apiResponse);
$object = json_decode(json_encode($xml));
```

Error Message is:

```
simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : internal error: Huge input lookup
```

I google and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15010460/4807414) on stackoverflow and changed my code to

```
simplexml_load_string($apiResponse, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_PARSEHUGE)
```

But, error is still same. Anyone has got any Idea? Thank you in advance

Comment: Not related to your problem, but please don't use `$object = json_decode(json_encode($xml));`. You're basically throwing away [all the convenience features that make SimpleXML useful](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php), and potentially also throwing away data (because XML and JSON can't neatly express the same structures).

Comment: Yes, thank you for the suggestion @IMSoP. I will try to implement it. BTW Is there any solution to my problem currently facing?

Comment: Did this ever get answered ??